# Comparison under 2 conditions

Tags: r

I have a little problem,
i have these parameters:

```
df <- data.frame(Equip = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                 Notif = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4),
                 Component = c("Dichtung","Motor","Getriebe","Service","Motor","Lüftung","Dichtring","Motor","Getriebe","Dichtring"),
                rank= c(1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2))
```

Now i want to have a comparison, looking just for one `Equip`, and if the used `Components` in the first `rank`, are the same as in the second `rank` ( just by the same `Equip`):

On 2 ways:

The first: are all Components the same?

Is any( minimum 1) Component the same?

I need a high automatic solution, because my dataset has more than 150k rows.

The desired answer could be a vector with just boolean expressions, including TRUE and FALSE.

So for the example above,

`answer <- c(TRUE,TRUE)`

Because Equip 1 rank 1 Component: Motor  "AND" Equip 1 rank2 is the  Component: Motor as well.
( An Example for the 1 desired way)

Thank you very much for your help =)

---

i used the comment function but i can not show the problem, because i want to show the code.

Please sorry for that..

the original data have more then 2 ranks now i want to combine rank x with rank x+1 in one step,for this is used a for this i used a foor loop in the function but it does not work any idea?

```
a <- lapply(split(df,df$Equips),function(x){
 for(i in 1:8){
  ll <- split(x,x$rank) 
if(length(ll)>i )
 ii <- intersect(ll[[i]]$Comps,ll[[i+1]]$Comps ) 
else ii <- NA c(length(ii)> 0 && !is.na(ii),ii) 
} 
})
 b <- unlist(a) 
c <- table(b,b) 
rowSums(c)
```

any idea what i can do for it ( the main idea is to have the result of 1-2,2-3,3-4 etc in one step!

Comment: What are your desired results ? Could you show us an example using the data you've posted ?

Comment: For the same Equip (e.g. = 1), if one of the components in one rank is repeated in the other rank you want result = true ? So, just one boolean for each Equip value ?

Comment: Yes this is the first step i want to have. The second would be if all the components are the same. But you got what i mean, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

package `plyr` is suitable for group  manipulation

```
dat.r <- dlply(df ,.(Equip),function(x){      # I split by Equipe
  ll <- split(x,x$rank)                       # I split by rank

  if(length(ll)> 1)
    ii <- intersect(ll[[1]]$Comps,ll[[2]]$Comps ) ## test intersection
  else 
    ii <- NA
  c(length(ii)> 0 && !is.na(ii),ii)                        ## the result
})
```

here I get the the comparaison result and the component name

```
dat.r
$`1`
[1] "TRUE"  "Motor"
```

Edit:  here the result with base package(no internet)

```
lapply(split(df,df$Equip),function(x){      # I split by Equipe
  ll <- split(x,x$rank)                       # I split by rank
  if(length(ll)> 1)
    ii <- intersect(ll[[1]]$Comps,ll[[2]]$Comps ) ## test intersection
  else 
    ii <- NA
  c(length(ii)> 0 && !is.na(ii),ii)                                          ## the result
})

$`1`
[1] "TRUE"  "Motor"

$`2`
[1] "TRUE"      "Dichtring"
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean? The idea to get the information of the "again used" Component is very useful. If you mean this i would like to have this information. Like i told in my topic, its a big data set and i have to summarize it, like looking up which Component is used often and which not. like this. Its the first step of my analysis.

Comment: the data is on the same structure as in the given example, there are just two different things, there are more then 2 ranks( but i tested it and this was not the reason that it doen't work) and the other thing is, that the data set is so big. I also think that a lapply solution is (quite difficult to look at). Is there another possibility to do it ? really thanks for your help =)

Comment: I really do not know what to do, there is still the error code: " Subscript out of bounds" would a rle of the vectors would help you?      rle(df$rank)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:8750] 5 1 4 34 2 29 1 8 1 8 ...
  values : int [1:8750] 1 2 3 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...
> rle(df$Equips)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:20268] 1 2 7 1 1 1 3 2 2 2 ...
  values : int [1:20268] 10024820 10025441 10040292 10045800 10050420 10062984 10071240 10083675 10090325 10099139 ...

Comment: str(df$Comps)
 Factor w/ 16 levels "Burner","Commercial",..: 16 NA NA 14 16 8 16 10 16 16 ...
                                                                     does it something to do with the "NA"'s ?? Thank you for your help

Comment: Comps is you're component column?

Comment: oh sorry for that, i was thinking that i change it correctliy, yes Comps is Component and Equips is Equip ( many changes of the names because of many tests) sorry for that...... is also used the plyr package because but like i told the same problem....

Comment: @Daniel you have a problem because you suppose you have 2 different when you split by Equipments!

Comment: Just I am curious , you will use it for professional use? which domain?

Comment: theoriginal data have more then 2 ranks now i want to combine rank x with rank x+1 in one step,for this is used a for this i used a foor loop in the function but it does not work any idea? <code> a <- lapply(split(df,df$Equips),function(x){   
for(i in 1:8){
ll <- split(x,x$rank)            
  if(length(ll)>i )
    ii <- intersect(ll[[i]]$Comps,ll[[i+1]]$Comps ) 
  else 
    ii <- NA
  c(length(ii)> 0 && !is.na(ii),ii)                   
}
})
b <- unlist(a)
c <- table(b,b)
rowSums(c) </code> any idea??? @agstudy

Comment: Just for my understanding, if i have an Equip group with more than 2 ranks, expecially 4, can is do it like that, that i just take a look for these Equips with 2 ranks( like in the given example) and then in for these ranks with expecially 4 ranks? so that i can make subgroups again where just to the Equips were looked which have the same number of ranks ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```
df <- data.frame(Equip = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                 Notif = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4),
                 Component = c("Dichtung","Motor","Getriebe","Service","Motor","Lüftung","Dichtring","Motor","Getriebe","Dichtring"),
                 rank= c(1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2))


allComponents <- function(subDf){
  setequal(subDf[subDf$rank==1,'Component'],subDf[subDf$rank==2,'Component'])
}

anyComponents <- function(subDf){
  length(intersect(subDf[subDf$rank==1,'Component'],subDf[subDf$rank==2,'Component'])) > 0
}

# all components are equal
res1 <- by(df,INDICES=df$Equip,FUN=allComponents)
# at least one component equal
res2 <- by(df,INDICES=df$Equip,FUN=anyComponents)

as.vector(res1)
> FALSE, FALSE

as.vector(res2)
> TRUE, TRUE
```